# How to debug a contract binary without source code?

Tags: truffle, contract-debugging, bscscan

I'm trying to debug a transaction on BSC network, the contract is not written by myself and it's not open source, is it possible to debug the transaction at assembly level?

I tried the ["Remix Debugger"](https://bscscan.com/remix?txhash=0x7a0ae8f30547b1a48c387d51890b4a5c75a4b77bb4a2e1640f7cfb5b1b2c147f) from "bscscan.com", it doesn't work and shows error like

> Access to XMLHttpRequest ... has been blocked by CORS policy: ...

Also tried truffle: `truffle debug 0x..tx_id... --network bsc`, it shows error:

> Error [ERR_UNHANDLED_ERROR]: Unhandled error. ({ code: -32000, message: 'header not found' })

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is none, so I made one: https://github.com/aj3423/edb
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can't do this,  you can try with the op codes of the functions which is very very hard.

Comment: Debugging through the assembly op codes is exactly what I want, like reverse engineering an executable binary, if it's possible.

Comment: it is very hard. Go into the address of the smart contract's page BSC exploerer and there you can find it

Comment: I tried but not work, as mentioned in the post, there is an error in dev-tools says "blocked by CORS policy".